# I cannot see case emails at account level

Tags: email, configuration, email2case

If a customer send to our email2case address, e.g., support@X.com then a case is created and the email is logged on the case, however the email does not show up at the account level, is this a design feature or is there a configuration that will solve for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember rightly the object created on inbound is an EmailMessage not a Task. The Tasks are visible on Accounts but EmailMessages are only available on Cases. You should see outbound Emails under Case Task history, meaning I would expect them to appear under the Account Task history as well.

I'm not aware of a reason why the inbound email doesn't also create a Task. I just had a quick look to if you could do it with a workflow on EmailMessage but Task isn't an option. If you wanted a Task for an inbound EmailMessage I think you would be able to use the process builder or otherwise a trigger to do it.